# Squared Sums with aggregateByKey PySpark

Tags: pyspark, aggregate, standard-deviation

I have the data set a,

`a = sc.parallelize([((1,2),(10,20,[1,3])),((1,2),(30,40,[1]))])`

and I need the following:

- (1,2) is going to be the key
- Since I want to calculate the streaming standard deviation of the first two values, I need to evaluate the 
  pure sums and sums of squares for each of these values. In other words, I need to 
  sumx=(10+30), sumx^2=(10^2 + 30^2) for the first value, 
  and 
  sumx=(20+40), sumx^2=(20^2 + 40^2) for the second value.
- for the final value (the lists), I just want to concatenate them.

The final result needs to be:

`([(1,2),(40,1000,60,2000,[1,3])])`

Here is my code:

`a.aggregateByKey((0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,[]),\
    (lambda x,y: (x[0]+y[0],x[0]*x[0]+y[0]*y[0],x[1]+y[1],x[1]*x[1]+y[1]*y[1],x[2]+y[2])),\
    (lambda rdd1,rdd2: (rdd1[0]+rdd2[0],rdd1[1]+rdd2[1],rdd1[2]+rdd1[2],rdd1[3]+rdd2[3],rdd1[4]+rdd2[4]))).collect()`

Unfortunately it returns the following error:
`"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'"`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hivecontext to solve this :

```
from pyspark.sql.context import HiveContext
hivectx = HiveContext(sc)

a = sc.parallelize([((1,2),(10,20,[1,3])),((1,2),(30,40,[1]))])

# Convert this to a dataframe
b = a.toDF(['col1','col2'])

# Explode col2 into individual columns
c = b.map(lambda x: (x.col1,x.col2[0],x.col2[1],x.col2[2])).toDF(['col1','col21','col22','col23'])

c.registerTempTable('mydf')

sql = """
select col1,
sum(col21) as sumcol21,
sum(POW(col21,2)) as sum2col21,
sum(col22) as sumcol22,
sum(POW(col22,2)) as sum2col22,
collect_set(col23) as col23 
from mydf 
group by col1
"""
d = hivectx.sql(sql)

# Get back your original dataframe
e = d.map(lambda x:(x.col1,(x.sumcol21,x.sum2col21,x.sumcol22,x.sum2col22,[item for sublist in x.col23 for item in sublist]))).toDF(['col1','col2'])
```